# Dask - diagnostics dashboard - custom info about task

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm using Dask to schedule and run research batches.
Those mostly produce side effects and are quite heavy (ranging from few minutes to a couple of hours). There's no communication between the tasks.

In code it looks like this, first I'm passing all the batches to process:

```py
def process_batches(batches: Iterator[Batch], log_dir: Path):

    cluster = LocalCluster(
        n_workers=os.cpu_count(),
        threads_per_worker=1
    )

    client = Client(cluster)
    futures = []

    for batch in batches:
        futures += process_batch(batch, client, log_dir)

    progress(futures)
```

Then I'm submitting repetitions from each batch as tasks:

```py
def process_batch(batch: Batch, client: Client, log_dir: Path) -> List[Future]:
    batch_dir = log_dir.joinpath(batch.nice_hash)
    batch_futures = []

    num_workers = len(client.scheduler_info()['workers'])

    with Logger(batch_dir, clear_dir=True) as logger:
        logger.save_json(batch.as_dict, 'batch')

        for repetition in range(batch.n_repeats):
            cpu_index = repetition % num_workers

            future = client.submit(
                process_batch_repetition,
                batch,
                repetition,
                cpu_index,
                logger
            )

            batch_futures.append(future)

    return batch_futures
```

Is there any way to pass some custom info about the submitted task to the dashboard?
All I'm seeing are just tasks `process_batch_repetition`. Could I replace it with a custom string, so I can see what batch configurations are being processed at the moment?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from Dask's BDFL [mrocklin](https://github.com/mrocklin).

> You can use the key= keyword to specify a key for the future.  This should
> be unique per future.  Dask will use the prefix of the key name to
> determine how it is rendered on the dashboard.  See the docstring for
> dask.utils.key_split for examples on how a key prefix is generated from a
> key.

So you can use it like this:

```py
future = client.submit(
    process_batch_repetition,
    batch,
    repetition,
    cpu_index,
    logger,
    key=f'{str(batch)}_repetition_{repetition}'
)
```

You just pass a unique string for this task. There are some forbidden chars (i.e. spaces), so expect some key errors.